# How to update multiple rows with on conflict clause?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do a bulk upsert (more than 50k rows per query) on a table with `ON CONFLICT` `UPDATE` clause.

```
Ex: INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2, col3) values (v1,v2,v3), (v4,v5,v6) ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) DO UPDATE SET col3 = EXCLUDED.col3;
```

Above's works just fine when `(col1,col2)` tuple is unique identifier to a row.

Happens that I need to the UPDATE affects multiple rows.

```
Ex: INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2, col3) values (v1,v2,v3), (v4,v5,v6) ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE SET col3 = EXCLUDED.col3;
```

I want the ON CONFLICT clause updates all rows where col1 = EXCLUDED.col1

But when I place a non-unique tuple on "ON CONFLICT" postgres result in this error: "There is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the `ON CONFLICT` specification"

There is a way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: If there is no relevant constraint what is the conflict you expect to see?

Comment: @RichardHuxton , I would expect to see a conflict with all the rows that have col1 = EXCLUDED.col1 . I think its not possible... but who knows.